# StringBuffer append - what happens inside jvm

Tags: java

I have a  while loop to do string append using string buffer. What happens inside the jvm, since the append method is synchronized , **does it check for lock every time on the object** and proceeds when an append is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some kind of theoretical sense the lock is acquired and released for every operation. In practice, for heavily used code paths, a lock coarsening optimisation is performed. So several operations in a row share the same lock acquire and release.

Also note that it tends to be the same thread using the lock (it's a per-instance lock). Typical JVM implementations will bias the lock for use from a particular thread, making the whole process surprisingly fast. As other have alluded, there is very little need to use `StringBuffer` multithreaded (much the same for other microsynchronisation), so you might as well use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind that, just use [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead:

> A mutable sequence of characters. This
>   class provides an API compatible with
>   StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of
>   synchronization. **This class is
>   designed for use as a drop-in
>   replacement for StringBuffer** in places
>   where the string buffer was being used
>   by a single thread (as is generally
>   the case). **Where possible, it is
>   recommended that this class be used in
>   preference to StringBuffer** as it will
>   be faster under most implementations.

But to answer your question, read this:
[**Java Tutorial > Synchronized Methods**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the synchronization of `StringBuffer` is unnecessary on single-threaded code (or multithreaded code where the `StringBuffer` is not shared between threads).

That's the reason why the [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) was introduced which has an *identical* API, but has non-synchronized methods.

Note, however, that the performance loss of those `synchronized` keywords should be absolutely minimal, because uncontested locks are *very, very* fast in Java.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not writing multithreaded code, there is no reason to use `StringBuffer`. Use `StringBuilder` instead. Its [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is identical, but `StringBuilder` is not thread safe.

> This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for `StringBuffer` in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to `StringBuffer` as it will be faster under most implementations.
>
> Instances of `StringBuilder` are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that `StringBuffer` be used.

Comment: And, more relevantly, it's faster

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the general rules of using synchronized method applies here. Also, if you are in a single-threaded scenario, consider using a `StringBuilder` and if you can't, at least try to use a Threadlocal version of your `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Even through StringBuffer is synchronized it is very difficult to use sensibly in multiple threads. i.e. if you are appending pieces of text in two threads like this.

```
thread A: stringBuffer.append("key1").append("= ").append("value1").append("\n");
thread B: stringBuffer.append("key2").append("= ").append("value2").append("\n");
```

Even though it is thread safe you can still get

```
key1key2= = value2\nvalue1\n
```

and many other combinations.